py2exe missing python modules
I am using Windows 11 Enterprise 24H2. Here is my pip list:
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
build             1.2.1
cachetools        5.5.0
colorama          0.4.6
ezdxf             1.3.3
fonttools         4.53.1
geomdl            5.3.1
numpy             2.1.0
packaging         24.1
pefile            2024.8.26
pip               24.2
py2exe            0.13.0.2
pyparsing         3.1.4
pyproject_hooks   1.1.0
pyreadline3       3.4.1
pywin32           306
setuptools        73.0.1
sip               6.8.6
typing_extensions 4.12.2
wheel             0.44.0


setup.py:
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['hello.py'])

python .\setup.py py2exe gives me an error:
setup(console=['hello.py'])

  21 missing Modules
  ------------------
? IronPythonConsole                   imported from pyreadline3.console.ironpython_console
? System                              imported from pyreadline3.console.ironpython_console, pyreadline3.keysyms.ironpython_keysyms, pyreadline3.rlmain
? System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard      imported from pyreadline3.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard
? __main__                            imported from bdb, pdb
? _frozen_importlib                   imported from importlib, importlib.abc, zipimport
? _frozen_importlib_external          imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc, zipimport
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? _winreg                             imported from platform
? asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy      imported from -
? dummy.Process                       imported from multiprocessing.pool
? java.lang                           imported from platform
? modes.editingmodes                  imported from pyreadline3.rlmain
? org.python.core                     imported from copy, pickle
? os.path                             imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, sysconfig, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? pyreadline3.keysyms.make_KeyPress   imported from pyreadline3.console.ironpython_console
? pyreadline3.keysyms.make_KeyPress_from_keydescr imported from pyreadline3.console.ironpython_console
? pyreadline3.keysyms.make_keyinfo    imported from pyreadline3.console.ironpython_console
? pyreadline3.keysyms.make_keysym     imported from pyreadline3.console.ironpython_console
? sets                                imported from pyreadline3.keysyms.common
? startup                             imported from pyreadline3.keysyms.common, pyreadline3.keysyms.keysyms
? test.support                        imported from multiprocessing.util
Building 'dist\hello.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.


